# Exercise on a quotient group over $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z ^2$ and let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $(1, 3)$ and $(2, 1)$, i.e.:

$$H = \{m(1, 3) + n(2, 1) : m, n\in\mathbb Z\}.$$

This exercise will help you understand $G/H$ concretely.

- Draw $\mathbb Z^2$ on $\mathbb R^2$.
- Draw the figure $P = \{\lambda (1, 3) + \mu (2, 1) : 0 \leq\lambda,\mu<1\}$. Note that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are nonnegative but strictly smaller than $1$. Determine the set: 
  $$\Gamma = P\cap \mathbb Z^2.$$
- Now let $(x, y)\in\mathbb Z^2$. Because $(1, 3)$ and $(2, 1)$ span $\mathbb R^2$ there are real numbers $s$ and $t$ such that $(x, y) = s(1, 3) + t(2, 1)$. Let $(a, b) = (s − \lfloor s\rfloor$)(1, 3) + (t − $\lfloor t\rfloor$)$(2, 1)$. Prove that $(a, b)$ $\in \Gamma$ and $(x, y) + H = (a, b) + H$.
- Argue that if $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ are distinct elements in $\Gamma$, then the cosets $(a, b) + H$ and $(c, d) + H$ are distinct. Conclude that $G/H = \{(a, b) + H : (a, b)\in$ $\Gamma\}$.
- Why is $G/H$ a cyclic group? Can you find a generator?

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Can you explain the issues you have had?

Comment: Which points did you do already? The first point is fairly trivial, and the second isn't that hard either. Did you do them yet?

Comment: Let's start at the beginning. Do you know what $\bf Z$ stands for?

Comment: I can't add a comment. I didn't know I created a new user. This post has been edited and the Z all are integers and R is all real numbers. With the first point I think the drawing is two circles. First circle is Z^2 which is inside of another circle which is R^2.

Comment: No one calls this «modern algebra». It's been just «algebra»  for the last 70 years! ;-)

Comment: ${\bf Z}^2$ is not a circle. ${\bf R}^2$ is not a circle. ${\bf R}^2$ is a plane, best thought of here as the usual $x$-$y$ coordinate plane, where you draw graphs of things in analytic geometry; the set of all points $(x,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. Now can you figure out what ${\bf Z}^2$ is?

Comment: In response to the comment that you posted as an answer, first of all, 3 is not a good example of a squared integer. And, no, you don't just put dots for the integers, nor for the squared integers, you put dots for the points $(x,y)$ where both $x$ and $y$ are integers. So, let's move on to the 2nd question. Suppose for a minute that instead of $<$ it had $\le$. Then $P$ would include $(0,0)$, and $(1,3)$, and $(2,1)$, and $(3,4)$ (which is $(1,3)+(2,1)$) --- do you see that? And $P$ would have everything inside the shape with those four points as corners --- do you see that?

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Picturization-} $Here is how $\mathbb{Z^{2}}$ looks like on $\mathbb{R^{2}}$.[image]

This should suffice for you to try the rest and visualize