# Algebra: Cylic Groups

Tags: cyclic-groups

Let $G = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z^2 $ and let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $(1,3)$ and $(2,1)$, i.e., 
$$H = \{ m(1,3) + n(2,1) \, : \, m,n  \in \mathbb Z\}.$$
This exercise will help you understand $G / H$ concretely.

1) Now let $(x,y) \in \mathbb Z^2$. Because $(1,3)$ and $(2,1)$ span $R^2$ there are real numbers $s$ and $t$ such that $(x,y) = s (1,3) + t (2,1)$. Let $(a,b) = (s - \lfloor s\rfloor) (1,3) + (t - \lfloor t \rfloor) (2,1)$. Prove that $(a,b) \in \Gamma$ and $(x,y)  + H  = (a,b) + H$.

2) Argue that if $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are distinct elements in $\Gamma$ then the cosets $(a,b) +  H$ and $(c,d) + H$ are distinct.Conclude that $G / H =  \{ (a,b) + H \, : \, (a,b) \in \Gamma \}$.

3) Why is $G/H$ a cyclic group? Can you find a generator?

Solution:

1) We know that $(a,b) = (s - \lfloor s\rfloor) (1,3) + (t - \lfloor t \rfloor) (2,1)$. Since $0 \le (s - \lfloor s\rfloor) < 1$ and $0 \le (t - \lfloor t \rfloor) < 1$ then we can let $(s - \lfloor s\rfloor) = \lambda$ and $ (t - \lfloor t \rfloor) = \mu$. Then $(a,b)\in P$.\
Since $(x,y) = s (1,3) + t (2,1)$ then $x = s + 2t$ and $y = 3s + t$.So we now have,\
$(a,b) = (s - \lfloor s\rfloor) (1,3) + (t - \lfloor t \rfloor) (2,1)$\
\indent =$(s - \lfloor s\rfloor + 2t - 2\lfloor t\rfloor, 3s - 3\lfloor s\rfloor + t + \lfloor t\rfloor)$\
\indent =$(s + 2t - \lfloor s\rfloor - 2\lfloor t\rfloor, 3s + t - 3\lfloor s\rfloor - \lfloor t\rfloor)$\
Let $j = - \lfloor s\rfloor - 2\lfloor t\rfloor \in \mathbb Z$ and $k = - 3\lfloor s\rfloor - \lfloor t\rfloor \in \mathbb Z$ since $ \lfloor s\rfloor, 2\lfloor t\rfloor, 3\lfloor s\rfloor, \lfloor t\rfloor \in \mathbb Z$. And since we know that $x = s + 2t$ and $y = 3s + t$ then\
$(a,b) = (x + j, y + k) \in \mathbb Z^2$. Thus $(a,b) \in P \cap \mathbb Z^2 = \Gamma$.\

2) We now must prove that $(x,y)  + H  = (a,b) + H$. By coset theorem, if $(x,y)-(a,b) \in H$, then $(x,y)  + H  = (a,b) + H$ is true. So,\
$(x,y)-(a,b) = s(1,3) + t(2,1) - [(s - \lfloor s\rfloor) (1,3) + (t - \lfloor t \rfloor) (2,1)]$\
= $(s + 2t, 3s + t) - [(s + 2t - \lfloor s\rfloor - 2\lfloor t\rfloor, 3s + t - 3\lfloor s\rfloor - \lfloor t\rfloor)] $\
= $(\lfloor s\rfloor + 2\lfloor t\rfloor, 3\lfloor s\rfloor - \lfloor t\rfloor) \in H$. Therefore, $(x,y)  + H  = (a,b) + H$.\

We know that $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are distinct in $\Gamma$. We want to show that $(a,b)+H \ne (c,d)+H$. We need to show that $(a,b)-(c,d)$ is not in $H$. $\Gamma = \{(0,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (2,3)\}$. Since $\Gamma$ is not in $H$ then the difference of any two distinct pairs in $\Gamma$ are not in $H$. Thus, $(a,b)-(c,d)$ is not in $H$ and $(a,b) +  H$ and $(c,d) + H$ are distinct. Since H is a subgroup of G, then $G / H =  \{ (a,b) + H \, : \, (a,b) \in \Gamma \}$.

3) i am unsure on how to answer this.

(I dont think i am missing anything on 1 and 2 but can you please check and can anyone help me with 3 please?)

Comment: What is $\Gamma$ in this context?

Comment: $\Gamma$ is P intersects with Z^2. So it is {(0,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3)}

Comment: 3) since G is cyclic and H is a Subgroup then G/H is cyclic. I don't know how to find. Generator.

Comment: And what is $P$? Is it the parallelogram (boundary + interior) formed from the vectors (1,3), (2,1)?

Comment: P=$\{\lambda(1,3)+ \mu(2,1): 0 \le \lambda, \mu < 1}$. $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are greater than or equal to 0 and strictly less than 1.

Comment: How is this any different from your earlier questions http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996419/exercise-on-a-quotient-group-over-mathbbz2 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999400/algebra-groups-and-closets --- we don't encourage posting the same question over and over. If it's not the same, it's close enough that you should post links at each question to the others, with text explaining how they differ.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for 2 isn't quite complete. For example, the statement:

> $\Gamma$ is not in $H$ then the difference of any two distinct pairs of $\Gamma$ are not in $H$

by which I presume you mean:

> $\Gamma$ contains no elements of $H$, so the difference between any two elements of $\Gamma$ is not in $H$

isn't fully justified. For example, what if it were the case that $\Gamma=\{(1,1),(2,4)\}$? Since $\Gamma$ is finite, you could just calculate all differences, and verify none are in $H$. A better way would be to note that $\Gamma\subset P$, so we can write

$$(a,b)=\lambda_1(1,3)+\mu_1(2,1),\quad(c,d)=\lambda_2(1,3)+\mu_2(2,1)$$

where $0\leq\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\mu_1,\mu_2<1$. So the difference of $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ is

$$(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)(1,3)+(\mu_1-\mu_2)(2,1)$$

Since $-1<(\lambda_1-\lambda_2),(\mu_1-\mu_2)<1$, and $(a,b)-(c,d)\neq0$, this difference cannot lie in $H$.

Now you have shown that all elements of $G$ are in a coset of the form $(a,b)+H$, where $(a,b)\in\Gamma$. You have also shown that distinct elements of $\Gamma$ produce different cosets. This tells you that the cosets bijectively correspond to elements of $\Gamma$, from which it follows that

$$G/H=\{(a,b)+H\mid (a,b)\in\Gamma\}$$

and moreover all the listed elements in that set are distinct.

Question 3) isn't too bad, given what you have already found out. You listed the 5 elements of $\Gamma$, and due to the bijective correspondence I previously mentioned this is equal to the number of cosets of $H$ in $G$, i.e.

$$|G/H|=5.$$

As groups of prime order are cyclic, then so is this one. Moreover all non identity elements are generators.

To perform arithmetic in $G/H$, you essentially are working with elements of $\Gamma$. All operations are identical to the operations in $G$, except if you leave the set $\Gamma$, you subtract an element of $H$ to get back in (this will give the same coset). So we could use this to show that $(1,1)+H$ generates $G/H$:

- $((1,1)+H)+((1,1)+H)=(2,2)+H$
- $((2,2)+H)+((1,1)+H)=(3,3)+H=(3,3)-(2,1)+H=(1,2)+H$
- $((1,2)+H)+((1,1)+H)=(2,3)+H$
- $((2,3)+H)+((1,1)+H)=(3,4)+H=(3,4)-(1,3)+H=(2,1)+H$
- $((2,1)+H)+((1,1)+H)=(2,3)+H=H=(0,0)+H$

So you can see that $(1,1)$ generates the group explicitly.